# Same name foe variables in a while loop

Tags: android

So my question  is...

Why does the following code complain about the variable name 'wordView' being initialized more than once..

```
 int index = 0;
    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(index));
    rootview.addView(wordView);

    index++;
    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(index));
    rootview.addView(wordView);

    index++;
    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(index));
    rootview.addView(wordView);
```

but this code doesn't?

```
int index = 0;
while(index<words.size()){
    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(index));
    rootview.addView(wordView);
    index++;
}
```

it's doing the same thing right?

Comment: Read up on "Variable scope." In the second case, wordView goes out of scope at the end of each iteration of the loop. A new variable of the same name comes back into scope when the loop advances. In the previous example, wordView never goes out of scope before you try to initialize it again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple.

In the first code snippet, **all the three variables are defined in in the same block** and hence the same scope, which is not allowed. In a block or scope, you can only define a variable once.

But in the second code snippet, **you have only defined the variable once in that loop block** or scope. After a single iteration of the loop, the scope of the variable finishes and the variable's lifetime ends. When a new iteration starts, a completely new variable is initialized.

It's all about the scope of the variable. You should not think that the loop means that the code inside the block will get copied several times. **With every iteration of the loop, the scope of the variables in the block ends** and a new scope starts.

Comment: Is your problem solved with this answer? Then please consider upvoting and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The **scope of the variable wordView** is what is to be noted here.

Below is what is happening:

1. In the first code snippet, the variable **wordView is being re-declared in the same block** which gives you the error. You cannot have a variable with same name in a block.
2. In the second code snippet, you have the variable inside a loop. What this means is that the variable **wordView gets a 'new meaning' at the end of each iteration.**